# Vim: cut line from cursor position and paste it to another cursor position

Tags: vim

I couldn't find this answer anywhere. I cut some line in Vim with either `dd` or `V`+`d` and I want to paste it inside brackets let's say. How do I do that?

`p` is paste after, and `P` is paste before, but I want it to paste at my cursor position.

Edit: I want to cut from certain cursor position (not whole line) to end of line and paste to cursor position in another line.

Comment: @Ciro Just tried those, didn't work.

Comment: But to you agree with the duplicate status? If so, let's close this and put all answers there concentrate knowledge in a single place: it's more productive.

Comment: @CiroSantilli Well I didn't find answer in that link, so nope I don't agree :)

Comment: Not finding the answer does not mean it's not the same question: explain it clearly in you question why the answers there do not work for you. merlin's answer was given there already there for example.

Comment: @CiroSantilli IMO, the question you linked is similar with OPs. but not dup. E.g there is no answer in that page to answer how to paste in line after a `dd`,

Comment: @Kent the answers there are for `yy`, but should be analogous. Well no big deal, I'll move on.

Comment: Apparently, your question is not clear enough. Could you expand it with a simple before/after example?

Comment: @CiroSantilli the big difference between yy and dd is, after yy, the line is still there, but after dd, the line has gone. so you can `0D` (following the answer in that link) but it leaves an empty line there, you have to postprocess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use either of those methods for cutting, you get the newline at the end of the line. With the newline, vim has to either put the line before or after.

To get the behavior you want, you should delete using `0D` instead to delete, and then use a normal `p` to put it into the cursor.

If you want to cut from current cursor position to the end of line and then paste it inside another line at cursor position, then navigate do the first line, do `D` to cut to end of line, then move your cursor to the place where you want to paste it and use `p`.

Comment: This one is good! But only for copying whole line. What about I want to cut from current cursor position to the end of line and then paste it inside another line at cursor position?

Comment: @user3763437, Just use `D` without the `0` and it will cut from the current cursor position to end of line.

Comment: note that `0D` **empty** the line, not **delete** the line. so if you want to **del** a line and paste, with the `0D` approach, you have to do: `0D` -> move to target place, -> `p/P`, -> back to the empty line -> `J` or `dd`

Comment: @Kent, That is a fair point, but whether it is important or not depends on the OP's needs. I expect the OP will let us know by selecting one of our answers. :)

Comment: @merlin2011 well I wanted to cut from cursor position to end of line and paste it into another line on the cursor.

Comment: @user3763437, In that case the first comment I made under this post should solve your problem. If you are only cutting part of the line, you presumably still want the rest of the line to stay where it is.

Comment: @merlin2011 You are completely right, don't know how I missed that! Just simple D and then p, exactly what I wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

try this, do `Y` or `dd` as usually, and create this mapping:

```
nnoremap <leader>p :let @"=substitute(@","\n","","g")<cr>p
nnoremap <leader>P :let @"=substitute(@","\n","","g")<cr>P
```

when you press `p/P` it pastes in default way(with newline). when you press `<leader>p /<leader>P` it pastes "in-line".

This is not so clean, because it changed the `@"`, next time you press `p` the newline is not there any longer. I was a bit lazy, put the `sub()` there, you can make a little function, remove the newline then paste, without touching (or restore after paste) the `@"`. and in mapping call that function.

I don't know if you did a `10dd`, what output do you want to have when you do an "in-line" paste. but you can do quite a lot thing in your function, to reach your needs.

EDIT,

I don't know how did you create the mapping, and "didn't work". here I put an animation:

[image]

Comment: I don't know, it didn't work for me... Anyways, what is considered usual approach for this kind of thing? I don't think I am alone who wants to cut code from some position until end of line and paste it into the brackets or inside parenthesis :)

Comment: @user3763437 see the update with gif, how it worked. in the gif.

Comment: @user3763437 if you do `D`, there is no in-line pasting problem at all... what on earth is your problem?

Comment: Oh I forgot \ sign. Yes it works perfectly, BUT, as merlin wrote, I can just `D` and then `p` and it's same exact thing, so I guess much simplier? Anyways, thank you. Edit: I didn't know I can use D, that's all I wanted to know.

Comment: @user3763437 no problem. my answer is not for resolving `D->p`, I didn't understand your question and post something else, and you didn't understand my answer either. :) anyway, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
v$d

(move to where you want to put what you just cut)

p or P
```